# Karate API - Assertion with fuzzy matching #number

Tags: karate

path: $.ActiveScriptJobID, actual: '17124', expected: '#number', reason: not a number

Above error message displays for below scenario

Given path 'admin/rest/activescript/job/17124'
 When method get
Then status 200
* match resp.ActiveScriptJobID == "#number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the actual response so your question is incomplete.

But check the JSON. It is sure to be a string (within quotes) not a number.

Maybe you need to use a regex: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching

```
* match response.ActiveScriptJobID == "#regex \\d+"
```

Comment: Yes response is (within quotes) "ActiveScriptJobID": "12779" . For assertion regex is useful in this scenario.Thanks