# Error "actual value is not a string" while performing assertion in Karate

Tags: karate

actual value is not a string error

Getting an error while performing an assertion

field1 = [1850,  700,  30]
field2 = ["1850.0","30.0","700.0"]

Error- assertion failed: path: $, actual: [1850,  700,  30], expected: '["1850.0","30.0","700.0"]', reason: actual value is not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because it *is* not a string. This will work:

```
* def field1 = [1850, 700, 30]
* def field2 = ["1850.0","30.0","700.0"]
* def field3 = karate.map(field2, function(x){ return ~~x })
* match field1 contains only field3
```

Please see this other answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761131/143475