# Convert Date format in Karate

Tags: karate

Convert date format in `karate`

I need to convert `field1` date format to `field2` date format for assertion

```
field1 = [2019-10-13 00:00:00.0, 2019-10-13 00:00:00.0, 2019-10-13 00:00:00.0]
field2 = ["2019-10-13", "2019-10-13", "2019-10-13"]
```

How do i get date format `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the function logic will change from your previous question's https://stackoverflow.com/a/57781381/8615449

```
* def field1 = [2019-10-13 00:00:00.0,2019-10-13 00:00:00.0,2019-10-13 00:00:00.0]
* def field3 = karate.map(field1 , function(x){ return x.split(" ")[0]} )
```

This is not exactly a date conversion logic but it gives the expected output as of field2.

Edit you use below as well,

```
* def field3 = karate.map(field1 , function(x){ return (new Date(x)).toISOString().split('T')[0] } )
```